# Java - How to design a method for search?

Tags: java, search, api-design

I am designing a decorator class which wraps a news search engine, so we can ship this class with a library to be used by other teams.

The exposed interface of this class is a Java-styled one, it takes a lot of parameters, then this decorator assembles these parameters as a search text to the search engine.

My method is something like the following:

```java
public List<News> search(List<String> keywords, List<String> categories, List<String> authors, List<Location> locactions, List<LocalDate> dates, List<SortRule> sortRules, int offset, int limit);
```

Yes, I know... This method looks ridiculously long, very error-probe and hard to use for the clients.

So, how can I design a better API for such a search functionality?

Comment: When trying to figure out good API design its never a bad idea to look at other good libraries design. One good one that comes to mind is Hibernates `Criteria` class https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Thanks, it's really a good reference!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try writing a wrapper class for applying the rule filters and then take the new object of this class in your current class. This way it would be much simple and cleaner.

For Example,

```
RuleFilters r = new RuleFilters();
r.addFilters(Type.Keywords, keywords);
r.addFilters(Type.Categories, categories);
r.addFilters(Type.Authors, authors);
```

Here `Type` is an enum which holds the details of the different rule filters like `{Categories, Authors, Keywords}` etc.

Finally in your Main Class:

```
public List<News> search(RuleFilters r) {
    /* Do Something with the rule filters */ 
};
```

Interface:

```
List<News> search(RuleFilters r);
```

**Note:** `public` keyword is not necessary in interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in [Effective Java](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2),You may consider using Builder Pattern. And that would be neat solution.

```
SearchParam search = new SearchParam.Builder(keywords).
  categories(categories).authors(authors).location(loc1,loc2).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by using bean or POJO for transporting Search Parameters.
After that you can use Some design pattern or filters to get results. But for just value transportation it is good to use Bean.

```
public class SearchParameters{

private List<String> keywords;
private List<String> categories;
private List<String> authors;
private List<Location> locactions;
private List<LocalDate> dates;
private List<SortRule> sortRules;
private int offset;
private int limit;
//Getters and Setters

}

//For one request
public List<News> search(SearchParameters param) {
    /* Do Something with the rule filters */ 
};

//for multiple request you could use List<SearchParameters> params
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take look on the [Elasticsearch Java library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search.html):

```java
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("news")
        .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("author", "jack"))               // Query
        .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("date_published").from('2016-04-01').to('2016-04-30'))   // Filter
        .setFrom(0).setSize(10)
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Which is basically a specialized implementation of the Builder pattern.